# How to build an efficient index for a large table from which a top row must be selected for each subgroup?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large table (~25M rows) with the following columns: AccountID, ItemID, Date, Price. The primary key is (AccountID, ItemID, Date). I need to efficiently select the price in the last record (Date < @SomeDate) of a group of accounts and a group of items. Not each account and item have a record for each date.

Basically, my stored procedure has 3 parameters: a table of accountIDs, a table of itemIDs and some date.

This is how my query looks like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT p.*, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
  (PARTITION BY p.AccountID,p.ItemID ORDER BY p.Date DESC) RN
FROM Prices p INNER JOIN @Accounts acc ON acc.ID=p.AccountID
          INNER JOIN @Items items ON items.ID=p.ItemID
WHERE Date<=@SomeDate)T
WHERE RN=1
```

This works correctly but kinda slow.
What sort of indices might make this query run faster given that i don't have any storage restrictions and the write time is not a factor?
Are there any other ways to optimize this query?

Thanks

EDIT:
I should also mention that i have a clustered index based on the primary key which is hit by the query with a Clustered Index Seek op. The UDTs i use are also indexed.

Is there any approach that might have an orders of magnitude improvement for this query?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the execution plan? If there's an index that can help usually it'll give you a script to create it. In general, indexes should search based on any column you are going to use frequently in a `WHERE` or `ON` clause and include any columns you might want to return

Comment: I do have an index based on the primary key and the UDT params are indexed as well. I'm looking for further improvement here (in orders of magnitude, preferably).

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT p.*, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.AccountID, p.ItemID ORDER BY p.Date DESC) as RN
      FROM Prices p
      WHERE p.Date <= @SomeDate)
     ) p INNER JOIN
     @Accounts acc
     ON acc.ID = p.AccountID INNER JOIN
     @Items items
     ON items.ID = p.ItemID
WHERE RN = 1;
```

I still don't think this will use the primary key index on `prices`.  So, consider writing this again as:

```
SELECT *
FROM Prices p INNER JOIN
     @Accounts acc
     ON acc.ID = p.AccountID INNER JOIN
     @Items items
     ON items.ID = p.ItemID
WHERE p.Date = (SELECT MAX(p2.Date)
                FROM prices p2
                WHERE p2.Date <= @SomeDate AND
                      p2.AccountId = p.AccountId AND p2.ItemId = p.ItemId
               );
```

This version can use the primary key index on `prices`.  You also want indexes on `@accounts(id)` and `@items(id)`.

Comment: Actually, the first query you wrote runs 2 times faster than mine. While this is definitely a good thing, i was aiming for an order of magnitude of improvement. By the way, both your and mine do hit the primary key index with a Clustered Index Seek op. Your second suggestion isn't correct logic-wise.

Comment: Is the p.date part of your Prices primary key marked as descending? This could help eliminate a sort in your execution plan (if there is a sort).

Comment: Yes, it is AccountID ASC, ItemID ASC, Date DESC.

Comment: @UriK . . . The second version should be the same, assuming that `date` does not have repeats for a price.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you're right. I didn't notice the inner joins on the outer subquery. Anyway, it's just twice as fast as my own. I say "just" cuz i'm hoping to find an order of magnitude improvement.